# Declaring C dll functions

Tags: c, vb.net, pinvoke

I am learning to make DLL for Visual Basic, so I made this:

#### DLL in C

```
// FirstDLL.cpp : Defines the exported functions for the DLL application.
//

#include "stdafx.h"
#include "stdio.h"

extern "C"
{
    __declspec(dllexport) int sestej(int a, int b)
    {
        int c;
        c = a + b;
        return c;
    }
}
```

#### Visual Basic

```
Public Class Form1

    Declare Function  sestej Lib "C:\Users\Blaž\Documents\Visual Studio     2013\Projects\FirstDLL\Debug\FirstDLL.dll" (ByVal x As Integer, ByVal y As Integer)

    Private Sub Button1_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles Button1.Click

    Dim vnos1, vnos2, izhod As Integer

    vnos1 = Convert.ToDecimal(VnosX.Text)
    vnos2 = Convert.ToDecimal(VnosY.Text)

    sestej(vnos1, vnos2)

    lblvsota.Text = izhod

    End Sub
End Class
```

When I run it I get this error:

> An unhandled exception of type 'System.Runtime.InteropServices.MarshalDirectiveException' occurred in WindowsApplication2.exe
>
> Additional information: PInvoke restriction: cannot return variants.

I obviously did something wrong but I can't find it anywhere.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you omit the return type in a VB function, it is assumed to be `object`. Since `object` maps to the native `VARIANT` type, that explains the error. You must specify the return type.

Rather than continue with `Declare` I suggest you switch to P/invoke. `Declare` was how it was done in VB6, but P/invoke is the .net way to do interop with unmanaged code. You would declare the function like this:

```
<DllImport("...\FirstDLL.dll", CallingConvention:=CallingConvention.Cdecl)> _
Public Shared Function sestej(ByVal a As Integer, _ 
    ByVal b As Integer) As Integer
End Function
```

This also allows you to correct the other error in your code. Namely the calling convention mismatch. Your unmanaged code uses `Cdecl`, but your VB code using `Declare` uses `StdCall`. The code above fixes that.

Comment: Thanks. Worked perfectly :D
I just had to add " Imports System.Runtime.InteropServices  " for it to work.